# Planar graph $G$ whose repeated strong products with itself are planar

Tags: graph-theory

Is there a planar graph $G$ whose repeated strong products with itself are planar?

Comment: planner = planar?

Comment: Hello. I don't quite understand your question. Are you looking for a graph $G$, such that no matter how many times you take the strong product of $G$ with itself you always have a planar graph?

Comment: If @HowDoIMath is correct about the meaning of your question, the graph with one vertex and no edges seems to do the trick. (It does the trick if your notion of strong products coincides with the one I was able to find on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_product))

Answer (score 1):

Recall that the mothers of all non-planar graphs are $K_5$ and $K_{3,3}$. In what follows we need only that $K_5$ is not planar.

> If $G$ has no edges then all repeated strong products of $G$ with itself have no edges either, hence are planar.

So assume $G$ contains at least one edge.
Then $G\boxtimes G$ contains a $K_4$ and $G\boxtimes G\boxtimes G$ a $K_8$, which is not planar. Hence we need only consider $G\boxtimes G$, no higher products.

If $G$ contains a three-cycle (or $K_3$), then $G\boxtimes G$ contains a $K_9$ and is not planar.

Assume $G$ contains a path  $a-b-c-d$ of length $3$ (with $a,b,c,d$ distinct).
Then we find $K_5$ in  $G\boxtimes G$: We have direct edges between most of the five vertices $(a,b)$, $(b,a)$, $(b,b)$, $(b,c)$, $(c,b)$ except $(a,b)-(c,b)$ and $(b,a)-(b,c)$, which are obtainable from the non-intersecting paths $(a,b)-(a,c)-(b,d)-(c,d)-(d,c)-(c,b)$ and $(b,a)-(c,a)-(d,b)-(c,c)-(b,c)$. This gives us a planar embedding of $K_5$, which is absurd.

[image]

Now assume $G$ contains a vertex of degree $3$ (i.e., a $K_{1,3}$), say $a$ is neighbour of $b,c,d$. Then in $G\boxtimes G$ most of the five points $(a,a),(a,b),(a,c),(b,a),(c,a)$ are directly connected, except $(a,b)-(a,c)$ and $(b,a)-(c,a)$, which can but be obtained from the non-intersecting paths
$(a,b)-(d,b)-(d,a)-(d,c)-(a,c)$ and $(b,a)-(b,d)-(a,d)-(c,d)-(c,a)$.
Again, this gives us a planar embedding of $K_5$, which is absurd.

[image]

> The only graphs that remain are those whose connected components are single vertices, or single edges $a-b$ (aka. $K_2$)  or two adjacent single edges $a-b-c$ (aka $K_{1,2}$). The components of $G\boxtimes G$ are then subgraphs of $K_{1,2}\boxtimes K_{1,2}$, which is planar:

[image]

**Summary.** The strong product $G\boxtimes G$ is planar if and only if the connected components of $G$ are subgraphs of $K_{1,2}$. For $n\ge 3$, the $n$-fold strong product of  $G$ with itself is planar if and only if $G$ has no edges.